# Firefox extension, how to call function in sidebar from main.js

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm new to creating extensions, I have a sidebar UI file with a javascript function called updateUI(parameter). In main.js, every time the page is changed, a new event is fired off:

```
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", doStuff);
```

Basically, the doStuff function generates some data. I then need to call updateUI(data) with the parameter being the data generated by doStuff. The purpsoe of this is to update the UI of the sidebar every time a new page is loaded.

However, no matter what I do, it always says the function updateUI is not defined?

Edit: I should emphasize that the updateUI(parameter) function is a javascript function defined in the HTML document of the sidebar itself, and my goal is to pass data from main.js to the sidebar and trigger execution of updateUI with said data

Comment: Did you have a look at (Communicating with sidebar)[https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar#Communicating_with_sidebar_scripts]

Comment: Yes. But it is not very helpful because (1) I need the event to fire every time the page changes, not when the sidebar is attached, and (2) the data I am passing to the sidebar is not static. I'm not just sending back and forth pings and pongs which is what the documentation suggests is all that it is capable of.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not just sending back and forth pings and pongs which is what the documentation suggests is all that it is capable of.

The [port API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29) is capable of sending JSON-serializable payload along with the messages.